# Slow web page (Jquery + bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, performance

I have a little problem...
I made a page, with BOOTSRAP and the Nivo slider (jquery) on it. 
I use boostrap for basic style, and for responsive design (resize for mobile, tablet...).

But, my page is veeery slow under Chrome only. I try to set off the CSS3 animation, the Nivo slider, but nothing to do... always slow.
Strangely, if I Zoom once (or unzoom) on the page, it become very smooth, like normal browsing. Only if i Zoom/unzoom on it after load it... Nothing on FF or IE.

ANy idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I encourage you to use Google Page Speed tests - they have great tips on how to make a page faster: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

A similar set of diagnostic tools is YSlow (also a Chrome plugin). I'd check it out, too. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ninejjcohidippngpapiilnmkgllmakh